# Config environment variables AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, aws-code-deploy

I have taken over codedeploy its all new to me. I trying to code deploy an ec2 instance to a Ec2 autoscalable group. I have taken over a appspec.yml which has a number of hooks, which calls a number of shell scripts.

I have modified the scripts to point at my s3 Bucket and Ec2 Group. The problem is that the scripts call some environment variables, set from user data. But I have no idea where these environment variables are, or what they are.

So my question is, if the env variables are in the path /ect/, is there a way I can look these variables up on the console.

Comment: Just connect to the instance via SSH or Session Manager and do a `printenv` to see you environment variables. But, first I suggest to check [Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html). Those variables are most like externalized there.

Comment: Thank you. That helped.  I did a printenv, and it printed out the env variables.